# Vue.js multiple checkbox filter

Tags: vue.js, filtering

I made two examples of Vue.js multiple checkbox filter: “Jobs” and “Games”.

“Jobs”: https://jsfiddle.net/ostapenko25/cw7kyp83/

“Games”: https://jsfiddle.net/ostapenko25/bu7hcvqg/

```
//“Jobs”
computed: {
 filteredJobs() {
  return this.jobs.filter(({ id, userId }) => {
    return (
      (this.checkedUserIds.length === 0 ||
        this.checkedUserIds.includes(userId)) &&
      (this.checkedIds.length === 0 || this.checkedIds.includes(id))
    );
  });
 }
}

//“Games”   
computed: {
 filteredGames() {
   return this.games.filter(({ game_id, season }) => {
     return (
       (this.checkedseasons.length === 0 ||
         this.checkedseasons.includes(season)) &&
          (this.checkedgame_ids.length === 0 || this.checkedgame_ids.includes(game_id))
        );
     });
   }    
}
```

They are  exactly the same except JSON data and names of keys and properties. But the first example works and the second one is not: when I try to use checkboxes, the list of Games just becomes empty. Please help me to find out were is my mistake in the “Games” example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is that your data source, the JSON feed, is using *strings* where your filtering logic is using *numbers*.

Basically, you're being tripped up because [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) uses the [*Same-value-zero equality*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Same-value-zero_equality) algorithm which doesn't coerce between types when comparing values. This means that if you populate your view's season filter with the *numbers* `2017`, `2018`, and `2019` but the data your are filtering represents seasons as *strings* such as `"2017"`, the implication is that `[2017].includes("2017")` evaluates to `false` because the `2017 !== "2017" evaluates to`false`.

Either use the same types in your filter, as in as your data uses, as in

```
data() {
  return {
      games: [],
      seasons: ["2016", "2017", "2018"],
      // etc..
  };
}
```

or account for the discrepancy in types by converting between string and number in your filtering logic as in

```
computed: {
  filteredGames() {
      return this.games.filter(({ game_id, season }) => {
          const seasonNumber = Number(season);
          return (
            (this.checkedseasons.length === 0 ||
              this.checkedseasons.includes(seasonNumber)) &&
            (this.checkedgame_ids.length === 0 || this.checkedgame_ids.includes(game_id))
          );
        });
      }    
  }
```

Working examples:

Using the same types: https://jsfiddle.net/p5e48w9c/1/

Converting to homogenous types: https://jsfiddle.net/dx1usgch/1/